# Why is vapor pressure constant at boiling point?

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, vapor-pressure, ideal-gas

At non-boiling point, I understand that when you add heat, temperature increases and also the amount of gas increases, so by using $PV=nRT$ at constant volume, the increase in $n$ and $T$ would increase $P$.

Thus, vapour pressure increases with temperature.

However, at boiling point, if you add heat, temperature does not increase and the energy is used to generate more gas molecules.

So if you are at a equilibrium where there is $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{A(l)}$ and $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{A(g)}$, after you add heat and shift equilibrium to $\pu{0.5 mol}$ of $\ce{A(l)}$ and $\pu{1.5 mol}$ of $\ce{A(g)}$ wouldn’t the vapour pressure increase even though temperature is the same by the ideal gas law– $PV=nRT$, where increase in $n$ increases $P$?

So why is vapour pressure is constant at boiling point?

Comment: Of course it would increase, if you keep the volume constant (as would T, by the way). Who said it wouldn't? The pressure is constant _in a constant-pressure setting_, but that's kinda trivial.

Comment: At the boiling point under constant pressure, the temperature is constant. Seems you are trying to make sense of this by looking at (likely sloppily written) definitions in a book. Keep the experiment in your mind!

Comment: By the way, "vapour pressure" is only defined for $T < T_{Bp}$. At $T >= T_{Bp}$, vapour pressure makes no sense.

Comment: https://www.chem.purdue.edu/gchelp/liquids/vpress.html

@Ivan Neretin The graph here seems to indicate a fixed vapour pressure for each temperature, even at boiling point? Thanks

Comment: @Karl From the graph I found in the link under my comment, it seems at though vapour pressure exists beyond boiling point as well? Isn’t vapour pressure jus the pressure exerted by the gas molecules of that particular substance? Thanks

Comment: Yes, there is a fixed vapour pressure for each temperature.  If you heat the closed vessel from your example, some of the liquid will evaporate, T will increase, and so will P.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin, but at boiling point isn’t the temperature fixed until all of the liquid is boiled off? In a sense, the heat is not used to increase kinetic energy of the molecules hence T remains constant. The heat is used to convert liquid molecules to vapour phase, so why in the graph the vapour pressure indicates that it is fixed at boiling point even when like you said, vapour pressure should increase when you continue add heat at boiling point? Thanks

Comment: It is fixed ***if you keep the pressure fixed***. Otherwise it isn't.

Comment: Imagine you heat water. When reaching 100°C, the water boils at ordinary pressure. If you carry out this operation in a closed syringe, the volume of the gas will steadily increase, the number of moles of gas will also increase. You may continue heating, the volume of gas will increase, but the pressure remains at 1 atm. and the temperature remains at 100°C. At the end, when all liquid water has been vaporized, heating the vapor even more will increase its temperature and its volume. But the presence of two phases prevents the temperature from increasing by heating.

Comment: @Barry No. It is the equilibrium partial pressure of a gaseous compound above a liquid containing the same compound. Without the liquid, *vapour pressure* is undefined.